# Oracle: Dynamic SQL with Update not working

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

I have this instruction

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET INC = 
(select INC from TABLE2
WHERE KEY = 'KEY_VALUE1' 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY);
```

This working fine if i run from sqlPlus or if I use in PLSQL but, if I using in Dynamic SQL, not working

```
sqlStmt:= 'UPDATE TABLE1'
|| 'SET INC = '
|| '(select INC from TABLE2 '
|| 'WHERE KEY = ''' || v_key_value || ''' '
|| 'FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY); ';

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlStmt;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN    
    dbms_output.put_line('{"errorcode":"' || SQLERRM);    
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

This instruction return this error:
`{"errorcode":"ORA-00933: comando SQL terminato erroneamente`

Someone can you help me?

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have a semicolon at the end of the string you are building and passing to `execute immediate`.

It's not the cause of your error.  But it would be much kinder to the database to write this using bind variables rather than concatenating literals.  Of course, since there is no reason to be using dynamic SQL for this sort of `update` statement, I'm guessing your actual use case is different and that you are actually using bind variables and/or there is actually a reason why bind variables aren't an option.

Comment: OMG!!! 2 hours and I couldn't see it, damn it!!!
I need some rest.
Thanks!